# How does my production Heroku app know what secret key to use if I am not supposed to commit .env?

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, jwt, production-environment

In my local file structure, I created a file called `.env` to hold my secret key for JWT authentication. When I deploy my app to Heroku using git and then try to send the API requests using Postman, I get this message:

> Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value

From other searches it appears this is because I didn't deploy my `.env` file where that info is located. However, the web also makes it clear you are not supposed to deploy that file.

Which is why I ask, how on earth is my app supposed do encode the JWT without having the secret key in that `.env` available?

Comment: You can set a secret key on Heroku as shown in the link here for deploying Node apps through Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.env` itself is simply a convenient way to populate [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) on your local machine. Heroku [supports configuration via environment variables out of the box](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

You can [set a variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#set-a-config-var) using

```
heroku config:set SOME_VAR=some_value
```

or using the web-based dashboard.